# I want to split the strings of the array, then assign numbers, and finally return them

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, split

I want to split the strings of the array, rearrange so the last name goes first followed by comma, and finally return them. For instance, Stephen Curry will be returned as "Curry, Stephen."

I'm so lost. I've tried many times now.  :(

```
function callPlayerLastNameFirst(){

var warriorsArray = new Array(5);
warriorsArray[0] = "Stephen Curry";
warriorsArray[1] = "Andre Iguodala";
warriorsArray[2] = "Klay Thompson";
warriorsArray[3] = "Andrew Bogut";
warriorsArray[4] = "David Lee";

var callPlayerLastNameFirst = names.split(warriorsArray[0]);
}

function replacer(){
return [warriorsArray[0]].join(' , ');
};
```

Comment: Does any of this code work? What happened to the quotes? Read about `split` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: ... Where is `names` given a value. Why are you splitting on a long string? .... Why not sit down and formulate an algorithm before hitting one key on the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you. I've been reading on that site plus MDN and watched on Lynda.com. I know I'm missing the point on my class assignment. :(

Comment: Seems like you still have problems with functions. For example, `warriorsArray` is *local* to  `callPlayerLastNameFirst`. You cannot access it in `replacer`. Learn more about functions on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions. Stack Overflow is *not* the right place to learn the basics of a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function callPlayerLastNameFirst(){

var warriorsArray = new Array(5);
warriorsArray[0] = "Stephen Curry";
warriorsArray[1] = "Andre Iguodala";
warriorsArray[2] = "Klay Thompson";
warriorsArray[3] = "Andrew Bogut";
warriorsArray[4] = "David Lee";

replace(warriorsArray)
console.log(warriorsArray)
}

function replace(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var words=arr[i].split(" ");
        words.reverse();
       arr[i]=words.join(", ");
   }
};
callPlayerLastNameFirst();
```

Comment: Sure, the function replace takes an array as parameter, in this case the array sent is your warriosArray with all the names strings. For each item in the array sent (for each full name), it will split the full name into words, reverse the order of the words and join the words in a single string with a "," as you wanted. Finally, that is saved in arr[i], which is the ith position of your warriorArray

Answer (score 2):

Try chaining splitting, reversing, and joining.

```
var warriorsArray = new Array(5);
    warriorsArray[0] = "Stephen Curry";
    warriorsArray[1] = "Andre Iguodala";
    warriorsArray[2] = "Klay Thompson";
    warriorsArray[3] = "Andrew Bogut";
    warriorsArray[4] = "David Lee";

for (var i = 0; i < warriorsArray.length; i++)
    warriorsArray[i] = warriorsArray[i].split(' ').reverse().join(', ');

console.log(warriorsArray);
//["Curry, Stephen", "Iguodala, Andre", "Thompson, Klay", "Bogut, Andrew", "Lee, David"]
```

Comment: Hey Dave thanks and for introducing chaining. I need to have my function though.

Comment: Is the objective of the assignment to replace all the items in the array with the new format?

Comment: Oops, I actually don't know. My classmate said I just needed the "function" in there.